# How effective is a level A hazmat suit for immersion in deadly substances?

Tags: everyday-chemistry, safety

I know that level A type hazmat suits can protect against minor splashes, but could somebody in one survive without harm after complete immersion for a few minutes in deadly chemicals such as sodium cyanide, high concentration (100%) hydrogen peroxide, and 80% hydrochloric/nitric acid?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Note that I'm used to standard lab safety measures including gas masks and masks mith independent air supply but I never used a Hazmat level A suit in research. You might want to take the following with a grain of salt!*

> > Sodium cyanide

($\ce{NaCN}$) is a solid with a melting point around 560 °C. While it is a solid, jumping into a pool of it shouldn't do any harm. Level A suits are like "your personal bubble" with independant air support. They are however not that heat resistant: Do not jump into a pool of molten sodium cyanide!

> > High concentration (100%) Hydrogen Peroxide

3% solutions of hydrogen peroxide ($\ce{H2O2}$) in water are used for wound disinfection, solutions up to 18% are used to bleach hair. (In German, the term *wasserstoffblond* was used for *bleach blonde*).

Much higher concentrations or waterfree (100%) ($\ce{H2O2}$) is another league.

Hydrogen peroxide can decompose into water and **oxygen**:

$$\ce{2 H2O2 ->[\textrm{cat}] H2O + O2}$$

The reaction releases some heat, may happen spontaneously and is catalyzed by some metals. Add some burnable material that can be vapourized and you have a **rocket propellant**. Think **Messserschmitt Me 163**.

If the hazmat suit is tight, and the material withstands "bleaching" by the hydrogen peroxide there's still the question whether hooks, valves, visor frames or any other metal parts, that might be part of the whole gear will catalyze the decomposition.

> > 80% hydrochloric acid

That does not exist in water. Water won't take up that much hydrogen chloride gas under normal conditions. Concentrated hydrochlorid acid (~ 38%) should be fine.

> > 80% nitric acid

That's close to fuming nitric acid and again a pretty strong oxidant. I'd say that you're safe, but don't take my word for it ;)

Comment: Just a few follow up questions, since you seem to be rather knowledgable. Would a level B suit withstand these conditions? Which chemicals would the suit not survive?

Comment: @football-fsj Thanks for accepting my answer. Honestly, I wouldn't know the limits of level B suits. I'm sorry! Just a minor hint: Follow up questions in comments are frowned upon here. Please submit them as normal questions. And most important: Welcome to Chemistry.SE!

Answer (score 3):

No, because Level A suits are not perfectly air-tight. They rely on positive air pressure to keep external fluids from getting in.

The pressure comes from exhaled air, which comes from a backpack tank or hose. The suits have one-way valves on the back that are protected by flaps. The zipper is also covered with a flap, but I don’t imagine it to be air-tight, either. Deep enough immersion would put enough pressure to stop the valves and make the zipper leak.